# Get selected row from Picker in Titanium Alloy

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, titanium, titanium-alloy

In Titanium Alloy I have made a Picker that consists of 'rows'. Users can select one of these rows and click a button to continue to the next window. What I want is that the button sends the user to the right window depending on the selected row in the picker. My code is as follows:

Alloy:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <Picker id="picker">
           <Column id="rows">
                <Row title="Row1" />
                <Row title="Row2" />
                <Row title="Row3" />
                <Row title="Row4" />
           </Column>
        </Picker>
        <Button id="button" title="Confirm" bottom="10%" width="115" height="50" />
     </Window>
</Alloy>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$.picker.addEventListener('change',function(e) {
    var selectedrow = e.rowIndex; // e.rowIndex determines row number
});

$.button.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    if(selectedrow = "3") {
        $.tabs.open();
    }
    else {
        $.tabs2.open();
    }
});
```

The problem is that every selection sends the user to the same new window, like the else-statement is being ignored. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.button.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    var selectedRow = $.picker.getSelectedRow(0);

    if($.picker.selectedrow && $.picker.selectedrow === "Row3") {
        $.tabs.open();
    }
    else {
        $.tabs2.open();
    }
});
```

use the selectedRow function [Titanium.UI.Picker getSelectedRow](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-method-getSelectedRow)

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code**

```
$.button.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    if(selectedrow = "3") {
        $.tabs.open();
    }
    else {
        $.tabs2.open();
    }
});
```

**change** `if(selectedrow = "3")` to  `if(selectedrow == "3")`

`=` is assignment operator and `==` is comparison operator.

Comment: Also  `selectedrow` variable must be global.